# MySQL List data where they share the same name/id

Tags: java, mysql, database

Print each movie name, then print a list of theater IDs and screens where it is playing/has played. For example, for the movie with ID=10, the output will look like
Frankenstein: (7, 17); (314, 73); (4345, 1)
This must be done for all movies. If a movie does not have any showings, you may show it with the list empty, or simply not show it at all (either will be considered correct for this problem).

Im having a hard time figuring out how to select the name then list out (TheaterID, Screen#)
Here are what the tables look like

I started todo the following from another example I found but doesn't seem like it would work.

```
SELECT movies.MOVIENAME, playing.THEATERID, playingSCREEN.#, count(*) as seqnum
FROM movies, playing
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
movies.MOVIEID = playing.MOVIEID 
ON p.plantid = pprev.plantid AND p.name >= pprev.name 
GROUP BY p.plantid, p.name
```

**Playing when MOVIEID is set to 93**

[image]

**Movies when MOVIEID is set to 93**

[image]

Comment: Please show the structure of your table and provide a data sample so we are able to help you.

Comment: I started doing this but it didn't look rightSELECT movies.MOVIENAME, playing.THEATERID, playingSCREEN.#, count(*) as seqnum
FROM c##labdataf15.movies movies, c##labdataf15.playing playing LEFT OUTER JOIN
     movies.MOVIEID = playing.MOVIEID
     on p.plantid = pprev.plantid and
        p.name >= pprev.name
group by p.plantid, p.name

Comment: Please add it in your question properly formatted. Also check those multiple #.

Comment: There is no MOVIEID = 10 in your data set.

Comment: this isn't the complete data set. the entire data set is vary long

Comment: Can you give me the expected result of MOVIEID = 93 for this data set?

Comment: ok i changed out the pics

Comment: i did get to chose what the names where

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. Also I think it's a bad practice to have `#` in your column name.

```
SELECT aa.MOVIEID, aa.MOVIENAME, bb.SCREEN, bb.THEATERID
FROM movie AS aa
LEFT JOIN playing AS bb
ON aa.MOVIDEID = bb.MOVIEID
ORDER BY aa.MOVIEID;
```

Comment: Do i make a for loop so get goes through all the MOVIEID's? the 10 was just and example he wants us to list all movies in the table

Comment: I deleted the WHERE clause. Yes, then you have to make a for loop to take each row's data.

Comment: Did you find out a solution?